# install ipkg via command line

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install ipkg-utils.

However, when I try to install it, it is unable to locate the package

```
sudo apt-get install ipkg-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ipkg-utils
```

I tried `wget https://dev.openwrt.org/log/trunk/tools/ipkg-utils` (the repository for ipkg), but it didn't work.

I inherited the code. ipkg was used to distribute and need to build an ipkg archive of a PIC build.

ipkg has been superseded by opkg.   I have opkg running ok but haven't built anything yet.  What I didn't find out was whether I could create an ipkg archive using opkg.

I've been googling for hours with no joy.  Does anyone know how to install ipkg?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you are trying to do is quite far from so called simple and you are doing a few things wrong.

First of all, `sudo apt-get install ipkg-utils` is bound to fail in the first place and to yield the error message you provided because such package does not exist in the repositories as it shouldn't.

Secondly, the link you provided as a "repository" is not a repository but a commit log.

Furthermore ipkg is discontinued and is commonly been replaced by it's fork: [opkg](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg), and ipkg does not have any official packages or sources available. You couldn't even find *that* information after hours of googling? Even though no questions should be issued in the answers: For what purpose should you need ipkg-utils and is it a must have instead of opkg? No offense, but doesn't seem like you have proper knowledge on package managers to start with...

That aside, you can get opkg sources via command `git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/opkg` and go on building those. On how to build from sources, here's a link to start with: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo

Comment: You couldn't even find that information after hours of googling. I found that in the first minute on wikipedia

Comment: Sorry, away elsewhere! Meant to quantify the above.<br/> I found out that ipkg has been essentially superseded by opkg pretty fast.  </br>However, what I didn't find out was whether I could create an ipkg archive using opkg. </br> [link]http://www.niksula.hut.fi/~ajhseppa/pixie/devkit/ipk-creation-howto.txt<br/>http://www.openstora.com/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_a_package_manager <br/>http://www.niksula.hut.fi/~ajhseppa/pixie/devkit/ipk-creation-howto.txt
http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Ipkg
But ipkg no work, I actually have opkg running ok but haven't built anything yet. New to this

Comment: Backgroung:  inherited code. ipkg used to distribute. need to build an ipkg archive of a PIC build. yikes!

Comment: @SeanJ that last comment is the sort of context useful in the _question_.